# angularjs nested ng-repeat of checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following ng-repeat list. I want to convert it to checkboxes.
Currently, it is repeating the category headings in **myJSON.mylist** and then repeating each **subitem** in each category in list mode. 
How can I convert the list type into checkbox type, so that ONLY subitems can be chosen?

```
<ul ng-repeat="s in myJSON.mylist">
    <li type="checkbox"> {{s.item}}</li>
    <ul >
        <li type="checkbox" ng-repeat="subitem in s.subitems">
            {{subitem.values}}</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

here is a [similar example](http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/wKBaxG).

Comment: the checkbox should be `<input type=""checkbox" ... >` not the `<li>` and you have to add `ng-model="subitem.checked"` if you have the  `checked`property like in example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="sin myJSON.mylist">
    <div > {{s.item}}</div>
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="subitem in s.subitems">
            <input type="checkbox" name="myname"
                   ng-model="myModel.myname[subitem.values]">
                    {{subitem.values}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is this:

You are using

```
<li type="checkbox"...
```

The example uses

```
<input type="checkbox" ...
```

Probably what you want is

```
<li><input type="checkbox" ...
```